# I can not get the code snippet below to output the proper results

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

The CSV file has about 6 entries of the word business along with several other entries that should match the ones below. However, the loop only properly brings up counts for "Business"

````
with open('majors.csv') as csvfile:
    for majorName in majorsList:
        ctr = 0
        print(majorName)
        #for line in csvfile:
            #if str(line.strip()) == str(majorName):
                #ctr += 1
                #print("WORKED")
        #print("Number of students thinking about " + majorName + ": " + str(ctr))```


Example output:
Business
WORKED
WORKED
WORKED
WORKED
WORKED
WORKED
Number of students thinking about Business: 6
Health
Number of students thinking about Health: 0
History/Social Science
Number of students thinking about History/Social Science: 0
Engineering
Number of students thinking about Engineering: 0
Communications
Number of students thinking about Communications: 0
Performance Arts
Number of students thinking about Performance Arts: 0
Education
Number of students thinking about Education: 0
Computers
Number of students thinking about Computers: 0
Other
Number of students thinking about Other: 0
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to open `majors.csv` for every item in `majorsList`.
Therefore your code will look like.

```
for majorName in majorsList:
    with open("majors.csv") as csvfile:
        ctr = 0
        print(majorName)
        for line in csvfile:
            if str(line.strip()) == str(majorName):
                ctr += 1
                print("WORKED")
        print("Number of students thinking about " + majorName + ": " + str(ctr))
```

Comment: If it worked for you then please accept the answer by clicking the tick above